# string.join method used in sharpDevelop

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I am trying to convert a double[,] to one string[] as my code shows below

```
double[,] completeDataArray = new double[25,4000];
string[] tarray = new string[4000];

for(int i = 0;i<4000;i++)
{
    tarray[i]=string.Join(",",Convert.ToString(completeDataArray[24,i]));
}
```

`

When I did this in visual studios everything worked as expected. But in sharpDevelop I get these 2 errors

> (1)The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string,string[])' has some invalid parameters and (2)Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to string[]'

The only way I can get it to work is to use another string array.

```
double[,] completeDataArray = new double[25,4000];
string[] tarray = new string[4000];
string[] tempString = new string[4000];

for(int i=0;i<4000;i++)
    tempString[i]=convert.toString(completeDateArray[24,i]);

for(int i = 0;i<4000;i++)
    tarray[i]=string.Join(",",tempString);
```

The only problem I have with this is I am running out of memory and when I use the tempString I get an out of memory error.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the version of mono you are using?

Comment: @giacomelli: ... or version of .NET. The OP doesn't seem to state anywhere he/she is using Mono.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6):

Your code appears to be using a `String.Join` overload which was added in .NET 4, and may not be present in the implementation of .NET (Microsoft's or Mono) you are using. Here is a summary of the changes to `String.Join` over time.

New overloads of `String.Join` were added in .NET 4:

```
public static string Join(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values)
public static string Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)
public static string Join(string separator, params Object[] values)
```

The following method was altered in .NET 4 by adding `params`:

```
public static string Join(string separator, params string[] values)
```

The following methods have been available since .NET 1.0:

```
public static string Join(string separator, string[] values)
public static string Join(string separator, string[] value, int startIndex, int count)
```

Here is the reference documentation for after/before the big changes:

- [`String.Join` overloads in .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [`String.Join` overloads in .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: You are correct.  I am using framework 3.5. The link you provided for .net 3.5 overloads still shows  string.join(string,string[]) to be available.

Comment: @user1757980 The difference is the addition of the `params` modifier in .NET 4. In your code, you are passing a `string` (not `string[]`) to the method, which in .NET 4 implicitly creates an array of length 1 to hold that value.